# Where does the story of “World Tree” or “Knowledge Tree” come in hindu scriptures?

Tags: puranas, language

According to this [site](https://alphaomegatranslations.com/foreign-language/three-myths-about-the-origin-of-language/) -

This story about human languages in a hindu myth/story, my question in which scripture does this story come from-

> **The Hindu World Tree**
>
> *According to one Hindu myth, there was once a very tall tree that grew
>   out from the very center of the earth. It was called the “World Tree”
>   or “Knowledge Tree”, and grew so tall that it almost reached the
>   heavens. The tree decided that it would keep growing so that its head
>   would be in heaven and its branches on the earth, so it could make all
>   humankind gather under it and prevent them from ever separating. The
>   god Brahma discovered the tree’s intentions and as punishment for it
>   being so proud, he cut off all of the tree’s branches and scattered
>   them all over the earth. Where each branch fell a Wata tree began to
>   grow, and with it a new language and culture for humankind.*

Comment: I don't see the reason for downvote here. It will be an interesting search I guess.

Comment: @Anisha from where you got this story?

Comment: @B.N.Bhaskar i have added a link above, on the word "site".